# Installing ffmpeg for Linux vps

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, discord, discord.js

I'm hosting my discord music bot on Linux vps (Ubuntu 16.04)
I tried to install ffmpeg, but nothing that I found at Google helped me.

Sorry for bad question, I'm new to Stack Overflow

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In this case including the error messages you got would help. This question might belong on superuser rather than here if it is not about programming.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -2):

Simply running

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

should do.

Assuming you want to use discord.js with voice functions, run

```
npm install ffmpeg-binaries
```

as well as

```
npm install node-opus
```

in directory of your bot.

Comment: The bot is not making any sound